# ¿Como puedo guardar y luego leer UserControl que fueron creados dinamicamente, en tiempo de ejecucion? en C#, WindowsForms

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Necesito saber como y donde es la forma mas optima en la que puedo ir GUARDANDO controles `(Buttons, Layouts, Label etc)`, y principalmente tambien `UserControl` que fueron creados en tiempo de ejecucion. La gracia, es que **UNA VEZ CERRADO EL PROGRAMA**, al abrirlo otra vez, se pueda nuevamente interactuar con esos controles que fueron agregados dinamicamente, es decir, que el cerrado del programa no interfiera en el dinamismo del mismo.-

Comment: Yo te recomendaría almacenar los datos de los controles en un archivo json, con datos como tipo de control, nombre, posicion, etc...y al arrancar la aplicación, recrear los controles usando esos datos. [Aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86503/Saving-the-state-serializing-a-Windows-Form) tienes un ejemplo, aunque en este caso usa xml en lugar de json.

Comment: Perfecto amigo, apelando a tu experiencia, porque crees que me seria mas útil hacerlo en JSON en vez de XML?. Aunque no lo creas pensaba trabajar algo similar a como lo mencionas pero con XML, y no lo había pensado con JSON. Sera mas rápido? eficiente?. Espero tu respuesta, si quieres ponla como respondida, no como comentario, porque me ayudaste a confirmar lo que tenia como opción y así te puntúo.

Comment: En realidad,para este caso en concreto la decisión de elegir xml o json creo que es mas bien una cuestión subjetiva. Si bien hay diferencias entre ambos formatos,para el caso que te ocupa creo que no son significativas. Propuse json por ser un formato flexible y compacto,y de muy sencillo manejo con Json.Net. Para explorar las diferencias entre ambos,puedes leer varios artículos,por ejemplo [este](https://www.oscarblancarteblog.com/2014/07/18/json-vs-xml/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma mas viable, sencilla y practica es la de hacerlo a través de **Json.Net**. Es una librería, descargable desde Nuget (Administrador de paquetes .NET), el cual me permite trabajar el formato Json. La forma en que lo haré es escribir dinamicamente en un Json cada vez que cree un control. Luego cuando cierre y vuelva abrir el programa simplemente cargo desde ese Json los controles.
La única desventaja es el pinchazo a disco que me envía cada vez que hago un back-up (que es mucho mas que lento que trabajarlo en RAM), pero si o si debo trasladar esa info a disco, por tanto debe hacerse ese trabajo.

Answer (score 1):

puedes marcar la clase como serializable con [SERIALIZE], anque como los botones no se pueden serializar tendras que marcarlos de esta forma "[NonSerialized]Button btn = new Button();" te adjunto un fragmento de codigo que podria ayudarte

```
 IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        String directorio = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "..\\Listas";

            PARA GUARDAR
                saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = directorio;
                saveFileDialog1.FileName = "";
                saveFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.btn)|*.btn";
                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Stream stream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                    formatter.Serialize(stream, "TU OBJETO DE LA CALSE VA AQUI");
                    stream.Close();
                }
                break;

            PARA ABRIR
                openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
                openFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.btn)|*.btn";
                openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = directorio;
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    g.Clear(BackColor);
                    grafo.Clear();
                    Stream stream = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
                    grafo = ("TU OBJETO DE LA CALSE VA AQUI")formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                    stream.Close();

                    "AQUI RECONSTRUYES TODOS TUS BOTONES, YA QUE UN OBJETO BOTON NO ES SERIALIZABLE"
                    Invalidate();
                }
```